# Badge achievement completion percent indicator

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

There are some badges which requires a certain number of "Actions". For example

> Commentator: Left 10 comments

or

> Announcer: shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses

Is there a way for check how far a person is from obtaining the badge?
Maybe it's easy to count the comments. It is also possible to control how many review I have completed. But I wouldn't be able of checking how many unique IP have visited a question I shared.

If this feature is not present, wouldn't it be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is a progress marking for the easier to achieve badges. You can see things on the review tab where the longer to achieve tasks do get progress bars.

[image: review task progress bars]

So in general, the developers of the site are aware that showing progress is good, however it's hard to know which items they may add features to. By asking here or the [main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and making a case for a specific progress bar, you might move the people paying the salaries of the developers to add that item to their work queue.

I personally don't see a burning need to address something as small as the announcer badge. If you work on asking a good question, the views will come. Also the sharing tools for social media will help if you have a question that's close to getting the views needed for that badge.

Comment: I knew about the possibility of seeing how many reviews I completed. My question was not about increasing the number of views. It was more a curiosity about the badge progress. Thanks!!

Comment: Perfect - hopefully it's clear that there isn't a dashboard for all badge progress that any of us can see.